# How to serialize a Java Class that is about to be written to CSV file with Jackson CsvMapper?

Tags: java, csv, serialization, jackson, sha256

I have a method that writes to the CSV file:

```
public static <T> void writeToCsvFileWithHeader(
        List<T> listOfData, Path absolutePathToFile, Class<T> clazz, char columnSeparator)
        throws IOException {

    CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
    try (SequenceWriter writer = mapper
            .writerWithSchemaFor(clazz)
            .with(mapper
                    .schemaFor(clazz)
                    .withColumnSeparator(columnSeparator)
                    .withoutQuoteChar()
                    .withHeader())
            .writeValues(absolutePathToFile.toFile())) {
        
        writer.writeAll(listOfData);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, however application should produce a SHA-256 of the data that is being written to the file. So I should somehow get bytes from the data that is going to be written to CSV file and then produce a SHA-256 from it.

SHA-256 functions for Java is not a problem. Problem is that I have no idea, how to convert my data listOfData into bytes, before writing them to the file and make SHA-256 of it.

Comment: Have you tried something like `mapper.writeValueAsBytes(listofData)` ?

Comment: @dariosicily this does the thing! Please post your answer so I could accept it
 Thank you very much btw :)

Comment: Glad to have helped :) , I posted my answer below.

Comment: You could also wrap a manually created `FileOutputStream` in a `DigestOutputStream` to create the hash without having to have the whole result in memory at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close to the solution, considering that as from the documentation [`CsvMapper`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-csv/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/csv/CsvMapper.html) is a specialized `ObjectMapper` with extended functionality to produce CsvSchema instances out of POJOs, then you can use the [`ObjectMapper#writeValueAsBytes`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.14/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#writeValueAsBytes-java.lang.Object-) method to obtain the result like below:

```
CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
//method that can be used to serialize any Java value as a byte array.
mapper.writeValueAsBytes(listofData)
```